# "client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0" - SSH error - MacOS 12

Tags: terminal, ssh, iterm, monterey

I'm getting the error `client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0` during a ssh connection on the command line when the target host is known (already saved to the `known_hosts` file).

This is the case since updating to MacOS 12 (Monterey). Does someone have an idea why this is happening or what has changed from MacOS 11 to MacOS 12?
When adding `UpdateHostKeys no` to the SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`) the error is gone. Is this a miss configuration on the server?